# Libreoffice+Python: Importing additional packages

Tags: drivers, python, libreoffice

I wrote some Python scripts that I use to get data from the web. These use the Selenium Webdriver bindings. This works fine with the system version of Python that I access via the terminal.

I'd now like to adapt those scripts for use with LibreOffice Calc (to further analyse the data) but attempting to run the Python Macro in calc breaks as it can't import the Selenium module.

Does anyone know how I can add Selenium (or other modules for that matter) to the Libreoffice Python?

(I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, Libreoffice Python is 3.4 and System Python is 2.7)

(The start of the error: 
Message: : No module named 'selenium'
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uno.py:268 in function _uno_import() [return _g_delegatee( name, *optargs, **kwargs )]
)

Comment: Have you tried to install Selenium Bidings in Python3?. It's not avaliable on the repos (or I can't find it) you will need to install it using pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Javier!

In case anyone else needs it, the correct command for me was:

pip3 install selenium --user

which installed the bindings to this folder:

/home/ --UserName-- /.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/